# Where does the EFS certificate belong when importing a PFX file?

Tags: efs

I have recovered and generated a PFX file for my failed filesystem, and on attempting to install it into the new machine, it is asking for a smart card.

Clearly it is attemptiong to install in the incorrect place, where is the correct location to restore a saved PFX file holding an EFS certificate?

i.e. User vs Machine, Trusted People vs Trusted Root Certificate Authorities.

Wherever I restore it to, the system remains incapable of deciphering the files.